# Display Object in The Same Page after Click on Hyper-Link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am working on a web page that will go on pure HTML5 and small Javascript.

I want to create menu near page text, that will include and display the contens of other html page when i click on one of the menu links. like that:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ravwC.png

I read about frames and i frames and i decided that i dont want to use them, but to use Object instead.

Here what i have i mind:

```
<center>
<right>
<li>link 1</li>
<li>link 2</li>
<li>link 3</li>
</right>
<left>
<object data="text.html" type="text/html"></object>
</left>
</center>
```

How do i display and change the contents from other html file in the same page, while clicking on menu link?

Comment: Why not use a div? `$("#divId").load(url)`

Comment: Can you give full example how to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would consider doing it

```
<right>
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="page1.html">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="page2.html">link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="page3.html">link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</right>
<left>
  <div id="content"></div>
</left>

$(function() {
   $("#nav > li > a").on("click",function(e) {
     e.preventDefault(); // stop the link
     $("#content").load(this.href); // href must come from same origin as the script
   });
});
```

**UPDATE**
Since some browsers do not allow local pages to be ajaxed (which is what .load does) why not just use an iFrame on your harddisk based pages - it will work on all browsers without ANY script:

```
<right>
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="page1.html" target="if1">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="page2.html" target="if1">link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="page3.html" target="if1">link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</right>
<left>
  <iFrame name="if1"></iframe">
</left>
```

Comment: How do you Arrange that in the index.html file? I try it but it is not working. Also, keep in mind that i working on standalone script which will not connected to internet.

Comment: You did not say anything about it not being on a web server. Then change the div to iFrame. I do not see any reason whatsoever not to. Add target="iframeName" to the links and you are set

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script language="JavaScript">
function doPage()
{
    var objTag = document.getElementById("contentarea");
    if (objTag != null)
    {
     objTag.setAttribute('data', 'http://stackoverflow.com/');
     alert('Page should have been changed');
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="Form1" method="POST">
<p><input type="button" value="Click to change page" onclick="doPage();" /></p>
<object style="visibility: visible; border: none;" standby="loading data" id="contentarea" title="loading" width="100%" height="53%" type="text/html" data="http://stackoverflow.com/"></object>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I DONT want to use Forms to do that. Im sure there are better ways to do that.

Answer (score -1):

You can put onclick action on each of the links.

Based od your example:
$("object").attr("data","text2.html");

Something like:

```
 <center>
    <right>
    <li onclick="$('object').attr('data','text1.html')">link 1</li>
    <li onclick="$('object').attr('data','text2.html')">link 2</li>
    <li onclick="$('object').attr('data','text3.html')">link 3</li>
    </right>
    <left>
    <object data="text1.html" type="text/html"></object>
    </left>
    </center>
```

I headnt icluded a head tag. You have to use jquery.

Works jst fine:
http://jsfiddle.net/rws8pa8z/